# Smooth scrolling with Bootstrap scrollspy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This question has been posted before but I think mine is different enough to justify a question.

First here is my fiddle (beware its quite large) https://jsfiddle.net/trrj3k68/
I'm sorry but there are some CSS that are not related to the problem, please ignore them.

The main problem was : I have a smooth scrolling, and I dont want scrollspy to highlight every menu button while page is scrolling. So I had to deactivate it while the scrolling effect is happening, and reactivate it afterward

But I created a problem that I can't identify yet.
To experience the bug, when you load the page, click on "Menu5". You will then scroll to 5, give it active class, but scrollspy will not function until you get back to the top of the page. The correct behavior would be : once you scrolled to Menu5 and you scroll going top, scrollspy should be working.

Here is my JS :

```
/*------------------------------------------------------------------
SCROLLING.JS
-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
// Scrolling animation - anchor buttons
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".scrollTo").click(function() {
        var t = $(this).attr("href");
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('#site-header').toggleClass('spy-active');
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $(t).offset().top - 50
        }, {
            duration: 1e3

        });
        setTimeout(function() { $('#site-header').toggleClass('spy-active'); }, 1e3);
        $('body').scrollspy({ target: '.spy-active',offset: 75 });
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        return false;
    });

});



//navbar
var distance = $('#site-header').offset().top,
    $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
        $('#site-header').addClass('fixed-nav')
    }
    if ( $window.scrollTop() <= distance ) {
        $('#site-header').removeClass('fixed-nav')
    }
});


$('body').scrollspy({ target: '.spy-active',offset: 75 });
```

Here is my final version, totally working in all situations :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".scrollTo").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().addClass('scrolling-active');
        $('.scrollTo').not($(this)).parent().addClass('nostyle');
        var t = $(this).attr("href");
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $(t).offset().top - 50
        }, {
            duration: 1e3,
            easing: "easeInOutQuint"
        });
        setTimeout(function() {   
            $('.scrollTo').parent().removeClass('scrolling-active');
            $('.scrollTo').not($(this)).parent().removeClass('nostyle');
        }, 1e3);
        return false;
    });
});

//navbar
var distance = $('#site-header').offset().top,
    $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
        $('#site-header').addClass('fixed-nav')
    }
    if ( $window.scrollTop() <= distance ) {
        $('#site-header').removeClass('fixed-nav')
    }
});


$('body').scrollspy({ target: '.spy-active',offset: 75 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add toogleClass in click action and this turn off scrollspy. 
So you must solve problem by adding class and set background to transparent in CSS.
Solution in fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bfc9x2n7/

```
$('.scrollTo').addClass('background');
```

Comment: yes I turn off scrollspy because I dont want every menu item to be highlighted when scrolling, like in your example ! sorry

Comment: I see, this works and is smart but the only problem is I still want the clicked link to have the active style while scrolling, like in my first example in my post

Comment: You can addClass on clicked element and change style. You can vote for my answer if I helped you

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code in full view,

Where you were going wrong was adding ***container*** class to the ***navbar***

It can be outside the nav.

```js
/*------------------------------------------------------------------
SCROLLING.JS
-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
// Scrolling animation - anchor buttons
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".scrollTo").click(function() {
    var t = $(this).attr("href");
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#site-header').toggleClass('spy-active');
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(t).offset().top - 50
    }, {
      duration: 1e3,

    });
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#site-header').toggleClass('spy-active');
    }, 1e3);
    $('body').scrollspy({
      target: '.spy-active',
      offset: 75
    });
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    return false;
  });

});



//navbar
var distance = $('#site-header').offset().top,
  $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
  if ($window.scrollTop() >= distance) {
    $('#site-header').addClass('fixed-nav')
  }
  if ($window.scrollTop() <= distance) {
    $('#site-header').removeClass('fixed-nav')
  }
});


$('body').scrollspy({
  target: '.navbar',
  offset: 74
});
```

```css
#site-header {
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  border-top: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#site-header .navbar {
  border: 0;
}
#site-header .navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#site-header .navbar-nav > li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16.66666%;
}
#site-header .navbar-nav li {
  border-left: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
}
#site-header .accessibility {
  position: absolute;
  right: -9999px;
}
#site-header .navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#site-header .navbar-nav {
  height: 74px;
}
#site-header .navbar-nav > li > a {
  position: relative;
  height: 74px;
  line-height: 55px;
  color: #4b4b4c;
  font-family: 'montserratregular', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms linear;
  transition: background-color 300ms linear;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
#site-header .commu {
  border-right: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
}
#site-header .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
#site-header .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: white;
  color: #e55240;
  position: relative;
}
#site-header .navbar-toggle {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
#site-header .navbar-collapse {
  background-color: white;
  padding-right: 0;
}
#site-header .navbar-nav > li > a:hover .fa-plus,
#site-header .navbar-nav > li > a:focus .fa-plus {
  color: #e55240;
}
#site-header .before-icon {
  margin-right: 24px;
}
#site-header .navbar-right {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
#site-header .fa-plus {
  color: #e55240;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-7deg);
  transform: rotate(-7deg);
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
#site-header.fixed-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
#site-header.fixed-nav .navbar-nav {
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  transition: 0.6s;
}
#site-header.fixed-nav .navbar-nav > li > a {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 26px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  transition: 0.6s;
}
.fixed-nav + div {
  margin-top: 74px;
}
.menu-button:hover:before,
.menu-button:focus:before,
.menu-button:active:before {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.active a:before {
  left: 0!important;
  right: 0!important;
}
.active a {
  color: #fff !important;
  background: red !important;
}
#site-header.fixed-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
#site-header.fixed-nav .navbar-nav {
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  transition: 0.6s;
}
#site-header.fixed-nav .navbar-nav > li > a {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 26px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  transition: 0.6s;
}
.fixed-nav + div {
  margin-top: 74px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<header id="site-header" class="field-master">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default normal">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="spynav" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#Menu1" class="menu-button scrollTo">Menu1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#Menu2" class="menu-button scrollTo">Menu2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#Menu3" class="menu-button scrollTo">Menu3</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#Menu4" class="menu-button scrollTo">Menu4</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#Menu5" class="menu-button scrollTo">Menu5</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div id="Menu1">
  <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

  <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris
    placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
    tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

  <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

  <ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  </ol>

  <blockquote>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis
      elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
  </blockquote>

  <h3>Header Level 3</h3>

  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  </ul>

  <pre><code>
#header h1 a { 
 display: block; 
 width: 300px; 
 height: 80px; 
}
</code></pre>
</div>
<div id="Menu2">
  <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

  <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris
    placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
    tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

  <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

  <ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  </ol>

  <blockquote>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis
      elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
  </blockquote>

  <h3>Header Level 3</h3>

  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  </ul>

  <pre><code>
#header h1 a { 
 display: block; 
 width: 300px; 
 height: 80px; 
}
</code></pre>
</div>
<div id="Menu3">
  <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

  <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris
    placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
    tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

  <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

  <ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  </ol>

  <blockquote>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis
      elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
  </blockquote>

  <h3>Header Level 3</h3>

  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  </ul>

  <pre><code>
#header h1 a { 
 display: block; 
 width: 300px; 
 height: 80px; 
}
</code></pre>
</div>
<div id="Menu4">
  <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

  <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris
    placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
    tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

  <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

  <ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  </ol>

  <blockquote>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis
      elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
  </blockquote>

  <h3>Header Level 3</h3>

  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  </ul>

  <pre><code>
#header h1 a { 
 display: block; 
 width: 300px; 
 height: 80px; 
}
</code></pre>
</div>
<div id="Menu5">
  <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

  <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris
    placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
    tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

  <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

  <ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  </ol>

  <blockquote>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis
      elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
  </blockquote>

  <h3>Header Level 3</h3>

  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  </ul>

  <pre><code>
#header h1 a { 
 display: block; 
 width: 300px; 
 height: 80px; 
}
</code></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry but as seen in your example, if I click on menu5 while on top of the page, every other menu item will be highlighted while scrolling!